# Add a 2D horizontal plane to a 3D plotly chart

Tags: r, plotly

I have the following chart with 3 variables, i.e. Date, Diffusion, and avg_Entropy:

[image]

I have all the rows from my dataset plotted in a 3D chart. I have included the current rendering of my plot. I would like to add a simple horizontal 2D plane into the plot that will serve as a threshold marker for diffusion. The only examples that I could find demonstrated adding regression lines which is not really what I wanted. Can someone please tell me what I need to add to include the plane plus a label which says "Threshold?" Here is my current R code.

```
plot_ly(color = ~factor(date), showlegend = F) %>%
  add_markers(data = tweets, x = ~date, y = ~avg_Entropy, z = ~diffusion) %>%
  add_paths(data = tweets, x = ~date, y = ~avg_Entropy, z = ~diffusion)
```